# does vyper support contracts making contracts?

Tags: vyper

I am trying to create manager contract that generates player contracts for a game. Right now I am using vyper to try and generate new contracts but that seems to be failing. I know you can have a contract make new contracts in solidity but that not work for vyper?
Thanks

Comment: what did you try? did you look at [create_forwarder_to](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/v0.1.0-beta.14/built-in-functions.html#create_forwarder_to)?